# useState Array is always 1 step behind

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to update an array using react's useState, however it is always 1 step behind.
I made a minimal reproduction using here:
[image: Edit sad-worker-9xv7dq]
Surely I'm misunderstanding how useState works as the onChange value triggers correctly.

```js
export default Home(){
  const [inputData, setInputData] = useState<{ exercise: string; weight: number }[]>([]);
  function procesWeightInput(exercise: string, weight: number) {
    const input = { exercise, weight };
    setInputData([input]);
    console.log(inputData);
  }

return (         
    <input
    type="number"
    placeholder="Weight"
    onChange={(e) => {
      console.log("The value", e.target.value);
      procesWeightInput(exercise.name, +e.target.value);
    }}
  />
)
```

Comment: useState is executed async. If you want to use the latest value you should use useEffect. [Here it's explained][1]


  [1]: https://dev.to/shareef/react-usestate-hook-is-asynchronous-1hia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`useState` hook is asynchronous which makes the `setInputData` update the `inputData` value after the `console.log()` call

See this StackOverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54069332/7916220

If you add a `useEffect` hook you can `console.log()` the value once it is updated even if the update hook is asynchronous. Update your code with a `useEffect` hook it should properly `console.log()` the `inputData` value.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(inputData);
  }, [inputData]);
```